# python: selectively split and combine alphanumeric strings in a file

Tags: python, string, file, strip

I am trying to replicate certain lines in a file and strip certain substrings from certain replicas. Each line is a string which I get through  a fileobject.readline()

```
Input:
Line1 : a -> b,c;
Line2 : d -> e,f,g;
Line3 : h -> i,j;
Line4 : k -> l;

Output:
Line1 : a -> b;
Line2 : a -> c;
Line3 : d -> e;
Line4 : d -> f;
Line5 : d -> g;
Line6 : h -> i;
Line7 : h -> j;
Line8 : k -> l;
```

In the output I want replicate the input line(a single string) to multiple lines(multiple strings) selectively .
Number of replicas/duplicates:
 For n  "," characters in a line, I replicate the lines (n +1) times 
where, n starts from 1, 
Strings to be put in replicas/duplicates:
replica 1: substring1 ->substring2[0]
replica 2: substring1 -> substring2[1]

and so on.

Could anyone please help me with the above problem?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please put some more inputs.

Comment: I have reframed my question. does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you can simply replace ',' characters with the '\w  ' pattern. It's more like a trick than a solution.

I wrote a simple function that can 'replicate' a line into multiple line follows your requirement. Note that this is for 1 line only.

```
def replicateALine(line):
    regex = re.search('\w -> ', line)
    if regex:
        line= line.replace(',', ';\n' + regex.group(0))
    return line

print replicateALine('a -> b,c,d;')
print replicateALine('e -> b;')
```

output:

```
a -> b;
a -> c;
a -> d;
e -> b;
```

Update: Because \w will only cover 1 character, if you need to cover things like snu_1opbb_1, try '\w+'

Comment: When I gave 'alphanumeric characters' ->  I am not getting the correct output, the initial part of string gets stripped. print(replicateALine('snu_1opbb_1 -> snuop1_1,suop2_1;'))
print(replicateALine('snu_2opbb_1 -> snuop2_2,suop1_2'))          Output:                                                                                  snu_1opbb_1 -> snuop1_1;
1 -> suop2_1;
snu_2opbb_1 -> snuop2_2;
1 -> suop1_2

Comment: Is it because '\w' in re  does not cover alphanumeric,special strings?

Comment: Ah, yes, because \w will only cover 1 character, if you need to cover things  like snu_1opbb_1, try '\w+'

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "a -> b,c;"
s = s.replace(";","")
a = s.split(" -> ")
b = a[1].split(',')
for i in range(len(b)):
    print('{} -> {};'.format(a[0],b[i]))
```

Read more about Python split and other string methods [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions). This is only first example, you shall be able to solve the other one by yourself.